# Show the data which is not chosen by under sampling approach

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sampling, imbalanced-data

Is there any way to get/show the data which is not chosen by undersampling approach?

```
rus = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=1, random_state=41)
x_res, y_res = rus.fit_resample(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this can be a little silly solution,

change your  y_res & y into a list and pass it to the code below , to get the unselected data,

```
set1 = set(y)
set2 = set(y_res)

unselect= list(sorted(set1 - set2))

print('unselected data :', unselect)
```

might be other good solutions, but this can be a funny one.

Thumbs up if you like !!

Comment: It did not work though.  I think I need to use pandas in order to manipulate the remaining dataframe.